# Page Builder by SiteOrigin conflict with Chrome

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome

I’m currently finishing up a website that uses the plugin “Page Builder by SiteOrigin”.

The problem is that it won’t open in Chrome but opens in FireFox. I have troubleshooted the problem to a conflict with this plugin and Chrome because if I deactivate the plugin, it works on Google Chrome.

I didn’t develop the website myself it was passed to me today (what a way to start the year) and already with this conflict.

Any help would be appreciated. If you need more info just ask!

Thanks!

Comment: You should contact the Plugin Authors.

Comment: @Blackbam I already have an open thread on the authors website. 
I was only hoping to see if this already happened to somebody else.